# "There was no attitude of poverty in his poetry" 絶無窮態

Tags: classical-chinese, traditional-characters, poetry, literature

more Joseon dynasty classical Chinese.

*In the poetry he had written, in the end, there was no attitude of poverty. How was it he never became well-known?*

其所爲詩絶無窮態。竟不振。何哉。

Does this make sense? Can it be more loosely translated as this person's poetry was really good, or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

穷 shouldn't be taken literally as *poverty*, instead, it is figurative *exhaustion of one's talent; reaching the limit of one's capability*. Also I am not sure 振 necessarily means *becoming well-known*, it could be simply *hanging on steadily*.

Without further context I would interpret the sentence as

> The poetry he wrote showed no sign of exhaustion, why didn't he keep going?

Comment: Thank you! This is in a 詩話 so something along those lines make sense, except it is preceded by a senior minister putting his name in the Hongmunrok, which was the list of the most virtuous literati in Joseon. 
_Therewith, he noted him in the Hongmunrok. But after a while he fell ill and died._
遂與於弘文錄。未幾病逝。
That's why I thought 振 must be well-known or related to the fact that he never got promoted.